# PRUM_EPISODES cookie

Tags: cookies

We have noticed an unusual cookie in our logs:

```
PRUM_EPISODES=s=1379338025465&r=http%3A//www.example.com/demo.html
```

I presume it's a 3rd party control on our site which creates this. Does anyone know which one?

Comment: We spent time time today working out where some unusual cookies being stored by our site were being generated from. We did quite a few google searches for the cookie name, but there were no results. When we worked out the source of the cookie thought it was a good idea to add this as a question/answer here so that others searching for the same info on Google could find this.

Comment: This one I also discovered the source of from a trivial Google search. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi Michael - I couldn't find this. Can you point me to the link please? I was only trying to get this information somewhere that could be found by others. There is no ulterior motive here. To me it seemed like a good piece of information for others to find the answer to.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=PRUM_EPISODES+cookie ... Of course, now _your_ post accounts for half a dozen of the search results, displacing the good content.

Comment: Hi Michael - what is the good content? There is no intent to cause a problem or displace good results. I can't see the good results you are referring to...? and we couldn't see them earlier today when we were looking into this, which is why I posted this first on stackoverflow, and then here when I was advised that this was a better home for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is created by the Pingdom Real User Monitoring javascript widget which measures on page response times etc.: https://www.pingdom.com/rum/